# React | CSS-Modules | Materialize-CSS: .browser-default not being applied

Tags: reactjs, materialize, css-modules

I am using Materialize-CSS in my React app with CSS-Modules.

I would like to use the default styling for input fields but when I try to apply the "browser-default" as indicated by the documentation linked below, the input fields still do not revert back to browser default styles.

https://materializecss.com/helpers.html#browser-default

```
import mStyles from 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
 <Field
  label="EMAIL"
  name="email"
  inputStyle={`${styles.input} ${mStyles['browser-default']}`}
 />
```

The only solution I've found that comes close is to overwrite all the styles with !important. Obviously, this is inconvenient and hacky.

```
 .input:focus {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Any suggestions for a workaround or what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just give `classname: browser-default` to `<label>` and `<input>` tag and it'll become just like a default text-field.

[CodeSandbox - Input Field Demo {.browser-default}](https://codesandbox.io/s/2oym2zoqv0)

```
<label className="browser-default">First Name</label>
<input
  placeholder="Enter name"
  type="text"
  className="browser-default"
/>
```

Comment: I'm looking to use a text input field.

Comment: You can check that again for text-input fields.